# Unable to execute Java command. Access is denied. (0x5)

Tags: java

While starting StartSonar.bat I am getting the below error, I added `wrapper.java.command=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin` in wrapper.config file.

```
Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Unable to execute Java command.  Access is denied. (0x5)

Advice:
Access denied errors when attempting to launch the Java process are
usually caused by strict access permissions assigned to the directory
in which Java is installed.
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A quick google search would let you figure out the issue easily.

Your wrapper config is almost correct. Open the file and edit the `wrapper.java.command` configuration key to:

```
# Path to JVM executable. By default it must be available in PATH.
# Can be an absolute path, for example:
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java
#wrapper.java.command=java
```

As you can see, you are missing `\java` in your path.

Hope this helps! Cheers and happy coding.

Comment: Here's the relevant guidance from sonarqube: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/ (see section "Adjusting the Java Installation"). Not sure whether that's the page being alluded to above ("quick google search") or not.

Answer (score 1):

you need to go

C:\sonarqube\sonarqube-9.3.0.51899\conf

put the below it will work
wrapper.java.command=C:\jdk-11.0.13\bin\java